# Query all objects within json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm looking to do a query on a column in my database but the column is of type jsonb. This is an example of the structure:

```
select json_column->>'left' from schema.table;

[{"id": 123, "name": "Joe"}, 
 {"id": 456, "name": "Jane"}, 
 {"id": 789, "name": "John"}, 
 {"id": 159, "name": "Jess"}]
```

Essentially I'm just trying to return all the name fields from this but I can't figure it out.

I have tried

```
select json_column->'left'->>'name' from schema.table
```

But this returns a blank value just.

I have also tried:

```
select elem->>'name'
from schema.table m,
jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'left') elem;
```

But that gives me:

```
ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work when I have a where clause inserted, for example:

```
select elem->>'name'
from schema.table m,
jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'left') elem
where m.id = 1;
```